# How to find all instances of an unterminated percent sign in a batch file?

Tags: python, regex, batch-file

I have a python function that looks through a batch file for potential errors, and the one that I am looking to resolve is to find any lines that have an unterminated percent sign. However, this function seems to be returning every  `%` sign on every line that has a `%` sign.

Here is the function I have at the moment, which is not doing what I need it to do:

```py
def check_unterminated_percent_signs(content):
    # check for unterminated percent signs
    errors = []
    for i, line in enumerate(content.split('\n')):
        match = re.search(r'%[^%\n]*$', line)
        if match:
            errors.append(f'Unterminated percent sign found on line {i+1}, position {match.start()}: {line.strip()}')
    return errors
```

Here is a line from the batch file that should **not** trigger the error:

```
set Log_File=%Backup_Folder%\Logs\daily_copy.log
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to count the percent signs. If the result is odd then you have a problematic line

Comment: I think your regex is matching on the 2nd % in that line, which is not matched with any further percent sign, since `re.search` will scan the whole string. It may be easier to use something other than regex to catch these errors.

Comment: Thanks DarkKnight and rassar - I failed to think outside of the box. Darknight - That might just work for what I need it to do.

Comment: That would only work on some files though, what about any which use arguments, `%0`..`%9` or with any of the modifiers, `%~f`, `%~dp`, `%~nx` etc.?

Comment: Yes - I am not sure how to get around that, unless I specifically look for each case by case ? Happy to take suggestions or additional solutions.

Comment: I'd recommend returning all lines that have an odd number of `%`s as "_possible_ mismatched percent signs" and let the user decide from that list if there are any that need attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks DarkKnight,

This is the code that solved my problem:

```py
def check_unterminated_percent_signs(content):
    # check for unterminated percent signs
    errors = []
    for i, line in enumerate(content.split('\n')):
        num_percent_signs = line.count('%')
        if num_percent_signs % 2 == 1:
            errors.append(f'Unterminated percent sign found on line {i+1}: {line.strip()}')
    return errors
```

Comment: You can also use `enumerate(content.split('\n'), 1):` so enumeration starts at 1 :)